# C++ accessing struct with #define?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I am testing some C++ code. Currently there is one problem that I can not understand the origin of.
The code is like this:

```
        typedef struct
        {
          UWORD tFollowUp_uw;

          union
          {
            UBYTE Control_ub;

            struct
            {
              BITFIELD8 Request_b1  :1;
            }b_st;
          }b_un;
        }X_CONTROLS;

    #define Request_b       (Controls_st.b_un.b_st.Request_b1)
    #define tFollowUp_uw    (Controls_st.tFollowUp_uw)

class Class_T20
{
  public:
      X_CONTROLS Controls_st;
}
```

So, when I test these LOC, I first declare an object `Class_T20_obj`.

I can only access the variable `Request_b1` by calling `Class_T20_obj.Controls_st.b_un.b_st.Request_b1`

I can not access the variable `tFollowUp_uw` by calling `Class_T20_obj.Controls_st.tFollowUp_uw`

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Why can't you? What happens when you try?

Comment: The code is hard to read due to an awful naming. Please consider proper names.

Comment: You'll need to show the code where you try to use those macros.

Comment: Your `#define`s inject `Controls_st.` themselves, so you don't need to repeat that when you use them. - e.g. just `Class_T20_obj.tFollowUp_uw`.  You don't need or want the parentheses in the `#defines` either - e.g. just `#define tFollowUp_uw    Controls_st.tFollowUp_uw`.  Anyway, a much better alternative is to add access functions to X_CONTROLS, then you can just use `Controls_st.followUp_uw()` or whatever you call them.  Macros should be avoided most of the time (see the C++ FAQ Lite for details)

Comment: actually, I can not change the code. This was written by another dev. I am a tester only. So I just want to find a way to access these 2 variable.

Answer (score 6):

> I can not access to variable `tFollowUp_uw` by calling `Class_T20_obj.Controls_st.tFollowUp_uw`

That's because `tFollowUp_uw` is an evil macro, so this is converted to

```
Class_T20_obj.Controls_st.(Controls_st.tFollowUp_uw)
```

which fails because `Controls_st` doesn't have a member also called `Controls_st`; and also because you can't put parentheses around member names like that.

Either use the macro, `Class_T20_obj.tFollowUp_uw`, after removing the rogue parentheses from it; or get rid of it.

Comment: With the stress on "get rid of it", I guess :)

Comment: even if I use "Class_T20_obj.tFollowUp_uw", it's failed also.

Comment: @user3118312: That's because of the parentheses in the macros. Get rid of them or, better still, get rid of the macros.

Answer (score 0):

In your comments you write you want to access the variable. That's easy:

`Class_T20_obj.Controls_st.b_un.b_st.Request_b1`

Okay, it's a bit work to write that, but its better than that evil macro, in many, many ways.
If it's the same `Class_T20_obj` all the time, you could shorten it by declaring a reference:

```
BITFIELD8& t20_Request_b = Class_T20_obj.Controls_st.b_un.b_st.Request_b1;
/* do something with t20_Request_b */
```

Or if you have different objects of type `Class_T20` and want to access that member, write a function that returns the reference:

```
BITFIELD8& get_Request_b(Class_T20& ct20) {
  return ct20.Controls_st.b_un.b_st.Request_b1;
}

//later:
get_Request_b(Class_T20_obj) = someBitFieldValue;
```

You write you are only testing the code. Use one of the given workarounds, if the author of the code is a foreigner and does not work at your company. I'd put the function inside a header that includes the foreigner's header with the definitions you pasted above like this:

```
//myxcontrols.h
#include "HIS_XControls.h"

//get rid of the polluting evil macros, they don't work anyways
#undef Request_b
#undef tFollowUp_uw

//free accessor functions
BITFIELD8& get_Request_b(Class_T20& ct20) {
  return ct20.Controls_st.b_un.b_st.Request_b1;
}
```

**But**: if the guy who wrote that code is in your company and you have to do acceptance tests, *please* don't accept it, throw that ugly bit of crapcode back into his face and tell him to make it right and clean. You'll help anybody who has to do with it in the future by not letting them have to cope with the same (and more) problems you have right now. You'll even help himself, although he might not notice at first: He gets the chance to learn and improve and be less cursed on by his fellow programmers.

Comment: Thanks for your very clear solution. I try yours and it works well. The author is a foreigner. I will try to contact him about this problem. ^^